# NT Authority\Anonymous Logon

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, permissions, sharepoint-designer

I just created an external content type in SharePoint 2010 using SPD. The connection works fine, etc. but when I go to my SharePoint site and try to load a list using the external connection, I get an error message saying, "**NT Authority\Anonymous Logon**". Does anyone know what can be wrong?

Kerberos has already been set up and I used user's identity' when setting up the ECT.
Oh yeah, I'm connectin to a SQL Server 2008 r2.

Thanks!

Comment: foundation, standard or enterprise?

Answer (score 2):

this post from BCS team blog on authentication in BCS can be help for you . This post really does a good job on explaining options

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bcs/archive/2010/03/12/authenticating-to-your-external-system.aspx

Hope That Helps